# What web frameworks and languages have the lowest development time?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to get a few web development ideas off the ground. Unfortunately I will be the only developer, so I'm focusing on getting a good debuggable, testable setup going that I can develop applications rapidly with.

Which languages, development styles and frameworks would you recommend for rapid development? Last time I checked RoR was the next big thing but that was a while back.

Comment: if u dont already know this, you are gonna spend time learning a framework. but i think we need to know which language you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I suggest this be CW... Also, I was just now coming here to decide a framework/language for my next web project and this was here. Woo!

Comment: Have a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227/what-is-the-best-multi-platform-rad-language/8293733#8293733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who are comfortable with Python there's also [Django](http://djangoproject.com).
I guess it is pretty much an equivalent to Ruby on Rails (although I never used Ruby on Rails). Django's concept is to have many autonomous applications which can be used together in order to build small to large scale websites. It has great documentation, although deployment can be quite a hassle. Unfortunately it's not supported by many hosters.

Comment: I agree. Django is a great framework for building a web app quickly.  I'd suggest going through a couple of the quick examples on their website.  It won't take long, and you'll get a feel for how rapidly you can build a web app.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby on Rails is a good choice for rapid prototyping. It's simple, clean and easily learned. PHP also offers a fairly low learning curve and a wide variety of built-in functionality for accomplishing most tasks. Both languages have their shortcomings, but on small-team projects for low to moderate traffic sites, you aren't likely to bump up against them.

Answer (score 4):

The one you know best.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP](http://www.php.net) with [Zend](http://www.zend.com) Framework has comparetively lower development time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with C# or VB.NET and HTML then ASP.NET is also a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another, [GWT (Google Web Toolkit)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is an awesome option.  It allows you to write all of your code in one language (more or less, you'll still need a bit of css --for the record ASP.NET allows this as well) and you can create really rich applications with all kinds of awesome javascript and ajax stuff without needing to know javascript.  Their tutorials are great and personally, I think you can get off the ground really, really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it matters more as to what languages you're most familiar with.
Whatever that language is, look for a good MVC framework for it.